# Python: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'list'

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have the following Python code (snippet):

```
    P = Data1_Wt[ D1D2_Pairs[:,0] ] * Data2_Wt[ D1D2_Pairs[:,1] ]
    P1 = ( P.reshape(1, len(P)) ).tolist()
    P2 = map(lambda xs: float(xs[0]), P)
    print ( map(operator.sub, P1, P2) )
```

I presume that from the above code, P1 and P2 will be cast in the form of lists (of same lengths). I wish to do a element wise subtraction of lists P1 and P2 to check whether or not they are the same. But, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'list'
```

What am I doing wrong? I will really appreciate any help here.

( Upon further research, I made some headway. P1 and P2 are almost same. Example:

```
P1 = [[1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4., 5.5]]
```

and

```
P2=[1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5].
```

They are both in the form of lists. )

Comment: Looks like `P1` contains lists, not floats.

Comment: 'P' is the array that I wish to manipulate. It contains 'n' numbers and is in the shape (n * 1), and I wish to recast it to a single row form ( 1 * n shape) and then convert that to a list. I think both P1 and P2 are valid ways of achieving this. So, both P1 and P2 should be the same (this is what I am thinking). I am presuming P1 is a faster way of achieving this. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @SiddTheKid What are `Data1_Wt` and `Data2_Wt`?

Comment: @khajvah: Data1_Wt and Data2_Wt are separate arrays (consisting of decimals) that I have defined before this snippet.   D1D2_Pairs[:,0] and D1D2_Pairs[:,0] are arrays of integers.

Comment: @SiddTheKid ok, these are not built-in types, so it's hard to tell. I suggest you debug by looking at `P.reshape(1, len(P))` and `P.reshape(1, len(P)).tolist()`

Comment: Upon further research, I made some headway. P1 and P2 are almost same. Example: P1 = [[1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4., 5.5]] and P2=[1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5]. They are both in the form of lists. I still don't know how to make them exactly the same. :-/

Comment: Just take the first element from the nested list.

Comment: I should have seen it. Thanks =)